# Piecewise regular curves

Tags: real-analysis

This is my first question on this site, so I hope I'm doing good.

Consider a continuous curve $\gamma\colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and a point $c \in (a,b)$ such that $\gamma|_{[a,c]}$ and $\gamma|_{[c,b]}$ are regular curves.

It means that $\gamma'$ is defined and continuous in $[a,c) \cup (c,b]$.

However, in general it could be that $\gamma'$ is not defined in $c$, since in general $(\gamma|_{[a,c]})'(c) \neq (\gamma|_{[c,b]})'(c)$.

Obviously the same applies to its module $|\gamma'|\colon [a,c) \cup (c,b] \to [0,+\infty)$.

Now my question is: the function $|\gamma'|$ is Riemann integrable in $[a,b]$ even if it is not even defined (not only discontinuous) in point $c$?

P.S. sorry for my english, I'm not native language.

Comment: Yes, the integral is still defined "in a colloquial sense". I.e. there is an unambiguous way to define it formally: Take any function $\widetilde{\gamma'}$ that satisfies $\widetilde{\gamma'}=\gamma'$ on $[a,c)\cup(c,b]$ and $\widetilde{\gamma'}(c)$ is arbitrary. Then just integrate $\widetilde{\gamma'}$ instead of $\gamma'$. This works because it doesn't matter for the integral what the integrand at a single point is. (In fact, if you know some measure theory, then recall that the integrand can be arbitrary on any set of points that have measure $0$.)

Comment: Thank you so much!